# Choosing between different methods when the first one raises error message for linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-regression, svd

I have a linear regression problem `(Ax=b)`. My initial approach that helped to solve some of my questions was using **SVD** and obtaining the chi-square and some other values that I am interested but it is breaking down for some cases for instance if my regression problem is as following :

```
>>> coff=
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.],
       [ 1.,  0., -1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., -1.]])
```

`coff` matrix is actually `A` matrix and `b` in regression problem is as following:

```
>>> b
array([-0.56168673,  0.8943901 , -0.56168673,  1.20952994,  0.33270337,
        0.31513984,  0.8943901 ,  0.31513984])
```

Using singular value decomposition method :

```
print "==============================SVD calculation============================"
U, s, Vh = linalg.svd(coff, full_matrices=False)
print U.shape, Vh.shape, s.shape
print s
S = scipy.linalg.diagsvd(s, 4, 4)
print allclose(coff, dot(U, dot(S, Vh)))
Sh=scipy.linalg.inv(S)

for i in range(Sh.shape[0]):
  if Sh[i,i]>1.0e+04 :
     Sh[i,i]=0

Uh = scipy.transpose(U)
V= scipy.transpose(Vh)
aa=dot(V, dot(Sh, Uh))
aah= scipy.transpose(aa)
S_sq=dot(Sh,Sh)
V_sq=dot(V,Vh)
covar=dot(S_sq,V_sq)
#The least square problem results
res=dot(aa,b)

wt=zeros(s.shape[0],float)
for i in range(s.shape[0]):
   wt[i]=0
   if math.fabs(s[i])>1.0e-04:
      wt[i]=1./(s[i]*s[i])

cvm=zeros((s.shape[0],s.shape[0]),float)
for i in range(s.shape[0]):
    j=0
    while j<=i:   
      cum=0.0 
      for k in range(s.shape[0]):
         cum=cum+Vh[i,k]*Vh[j,k]*wt[k]

      cvm[i,j]=cum
      cvm[j,i]=cum
      j+=1

print "SVD results for seventeen filters:\n",res
print "SVD's covariance matrix:\n",cvm


sig=zeros(cvm.shape[0],float)
for i in range(cvm.shape[0]):
  for j in range(cvm.shape[1]):
    if i==j:
      sig[i]=math.sqrt(cvm[i,j])

print 'Variance:\n',sig


chi_square=0
v=dot(coff,res)

for i in range(b.shape[0]):
    chi_square += (b[i]-v[i])**2


print "chi_square:\n",chi_square

reduce_chi=chi_square/(coff.shape[0]-coff.shape[1]-1)
print "Reduced-Chisquare:\n",reduce_chi
```

Well my approach is not the optimize approach but I need to see for instance what is the value for `Reduced-Chisquare` or `covariance` but it raises **singular matrix error** when I try to inverse `S` matrix but if I use the following procedure:

```
Least_squares,residuals,rank,Singular_values=np.linalg.lstsq(coff, b)
```

It doesn't give me any error and compute the regression problem.
**My questions**:

*First* : why this problem occurs using `SVD`?

*Second* (very programming question): How could I keep the first approach and use the second one just in case that one error raises in the first method?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the second one, one way is using try and except :) Use:

```
try:
     first_option blabla
except:
     second_option
```

You can even limit the except for that singular matrix error (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html; is this error numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError?)

I will take a look at the code now, to see if I can answer the first :)

Comment: Oddly I saw the documentation but I don't know how I could implement it, in the case that the first one would break down in any stage and then it tries the second approach.